# App crash when execute asynctask

Tags: android

my app crash when execute asynctask. I try to send data from android to the server but my app crashes when execute AsyncTask 
`       input input = new input();
        input.execute();

```
    mainActivity = this;
    latitude = "-6.711647";
    longitude ="108.5413";`


public class input extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{

    HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
    String email = user.get("email");
    String success;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Sending Data to server...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        String strEMAIL = email.toString();
        String strNama = latitude.toString();
        String strProdi = longitude.toString();


        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", strEMAIL));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", strNama));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", strProdi));


        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);

        try {
            success = json.getString("success");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();

        if (success.equals("1")) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "kirim data Sukses!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 
        else 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "kirim data Gagal!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
}
```

this my complete code http://pastebin.com/jRdxeQKG
and this my logcat http://prntscr.com/7p3vbz

Comment: What is the exception? Post your logcat.

Answer (score 1):

The reference `db` is null when you call `new input()` in `onCreate()`.

**Solution**: Just initialize `db` before calling `new input()`:

```
 db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
 input input = new input();
```

By the way, there are many issues from the design point of view, but this will solve (one of) the crash(es).

Comment: That should be another question though

Answer (score 0):

**1** Starting the name of your class with a lowercase letter is bad practice.`input` should be `Input` and should be a little more descriptive.

**2** Your db initialization should come before the call to execute AsyncTask

**3** You need to really understand AsyncTask before using it. You declare three generic types for your AsyncTask

`public class input extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {`

but none of them is used. Your doInBackground method should be returning an instance of type `NameValuePair` or `JSONObject`.

The first generic type of an AsyncTask is the `params`, that is what you intend to pass to your doInBackground method. You say it's `String` but do not pass in any String in `input.execute();` This is not a problem right now because you haven't attempted to use `args0`, but your app will crash if you try to. I just think you should really read about [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) first and understand the basics.It will save you a whole lot of trouble.Cheers.